# Docker build on github branch cannot find file specified

Tags: git, docker, docker-build

I'm attempting to build a Docker image on Windows 10 using the following command:

```
docker build -t cron_runner .
```

I however get the following error:

```
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in context path: readlink C:\Users\xxx\Tools\Internal_Tools: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The folder has a standard Dockerfile in it with no extension. The folder however is on a git branch that isn't master.

If I move the Dockerfile out of the Git folder into a local folder the docker image builds without any issues so I think the issue is to do with the fact its on a branch so there is a symlink issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you run `docker build`; docker copies your **context**; which is the whole directory where your Dockerfile lives in (except when you use .dockerignore).

It seems like a (broken?) symlink resides in the directory where your Dockerfile is; so either clean up the parent directory; either move the Dockerfile into a clean subdirectory.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleanup"? Its an initial git project with branches. Is it the fact I switch branches that is breaking the symlinks ?

Comment: git branches don't influence this; it is just the filesystem. Go into the directory where your Dockerfile resides and run `ls -la` ; then you might find the broken symlink.

Comment: you must have created a symlink to Internal_Tools somewhere?

Comment: I didn't but I just moved the root folder for the project out and remade it and it works. I did no linking, strange.